# Not receiving PayPal express transaction - Php

Tags: php, paypal

Apologies if this question has already been asked. I've been hunting around for a few hours and haven't found an answer to my problem.

I am pretty new in working with the PayPal api's, so please forgive me if I am blatantly missing something here.

I am setting up a test environment to gain an understanding of how to build a web checkout using the Express Checkout library in PHP. I have set up both a buyer and a merchant seller account and have used some of the examples in the PHP SDK to help me build a basic HTML input page, and ultimately succeed in transferring the funds from the buyer account to the merchant account.

The problem that I am having is that when I have completed in sending the money, and I then log into the buyer's sandbox account, I can see that the money was sent to the merchant, however the transaction has been tagged as "Unclaimed". Looking at the details of the transaction, it has been sent to the correct merchant sandbox account. When I then log into the merchant account however, there is no sign of the transaction.

I am using the "Sale" payment type.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the email address is verified on the sellers account.  If you still don't see it, can you provide the transaction id, the test sandbox buyer email address, and the test sandbox seller email address and I can take a look at it on my side.

Comment: thanks for the response.

I have logged into both the buyer and seller accounts to double chack, both accounts are showing as "Verified".

Here are the email addresses:

buyer - buyer@pixelpug.co.uk
merchant - info@pixelpug.co.uk

I have done another test transaction, with the following details:

token: EC-3PT718323A322131U
payerid: 7FGLE4JM3LJT4
currency: USD
amount: 15.50

transatcionid: 1U966361LE283944T

Again, on the buyer account the transaction is showing as "Unclaimed", and there is no sign of the transaction in the merchant account.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The payment is pending due to the following reason.  Sent in a currency the recipient does not hold and the recipient had Accept/Deny turned on.  Log into your seller account, and go to your profile and to the section for Block Payments/Payment Receiving Preferences.  This will then work going forward.  You can also go into the transaction details of the previous payments in the seller account and manually accept the transactions.

Comment: Thanks very much for getting back to me on this, your information was very helpful. I was able to amend the settings as you suggested and everything is working fine.